# PHP scraping page after JS injection

Tags: symfony, web-scraping

I'm having trouble scraping a website using `Goutte` in Symfony 5, `www.supercars.com`. The problem is that the data I need to **scrape**, is injected via JavaScript. Problem being the data returned from `$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.supercars.com/');` only returns the page source which has the dummy data before it is overwritten by the JavaScript. How would I get their JS to run before it returns the DOM? If not, how would I do this via a different plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a headless browser that will load and execute the javascript. You have many options. [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) is popular.